# How to "compile" ways and relations from OSM Planet

Tags: openstreetmap, osmconvert

I need to get political boundaries, house polygons and some other data from OSM. To do that I downloaded OSM Planet dump, converted it into `.pbf` format (cause its fast and doesn't take a lot of space). Then, created a streamer that imported `nodes`, `ways` and `relations` into MongoDB.

Now I need to **compile** `ways` from `nodes` (in each way instead of reference to nodes, put their coordinates) and then compile `relations` from them both.

I tried to do that using Redis (key-value in-memory database) as compact as I could (`id` as key + `lat,lon` as value). But couldn't even import nodes - it stopped on 14% (I have 128 GB RAM)

My next try was to do the same thing with MongoDB but it's too slow.

How can I achieve this?
Are there any tools like `osmconvert` or `osmfilter`?

I'm sure people do that somehow cause there are a lot of projects based on OSM, but I have no idea how.

Comment: Why did you download the planet and convert it to pbf, as opposed to say download the pbf version in the first place? https://planet.openstreetmap.org/pbf/

Comment: Regarding your question, check out https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/manual.html#filtering-by-tags and https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/56848/osmfilter-to-extract-all-admin-boundaries-as-areas-and-all-places-as-dots

Comment: @mmd I will probably use this method for now (filtering the data I will use before compilation). BTW, thanks for pointing out there is already a  `pbf` download option